# bq m10 keyboard layout

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bq, m10

How to switch to the Russian keyboard layout an external keyboard in desktop mode? Do not work in
Firefox and LiibreOffice, and work in mobile apps !

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with the bq M10 tablet.
There is a bug report on this matter:
[Bug #1574365: Ubuntu Touch needs way to switch external keyboard layout](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1574365).
In the description and comments, you can find a couple of workarounds, e.g.

> Switching keymaps is possible with the following shortcuts:
>
> Super+Space -> Next keyboard layout
>
> Super+Shift+Space -> Previous keyboard layout
>
> (same as in unity 7)

This workaround is useless for me, since I have an external bluetooth keyboard without Super button. But maybe it will help you.
In any case, I suggest you to vote for this bug report.

Comment: Super button is the Windows button or Command button. I'm sure your external keyboard has one of those two as I've never seen one without (mine has too - I have the Microsoft Universal Mobile Keyboard).

Comment: @Vistaus, I have Sony BKB10 bluetooth keyboard. It's designed, like almost all other compact keyboards, with Android in mind. It doesn't have a Super button. If it has, it's hidden very effectively.

Comment: Doesn't it have a home button? I have an older Motorola keyboard for Android that has a home button. Or maybe a similar button in your case.

Comment: @Vistaus, yes, this keyboard does have the home button. But it does nothing on M10. Pressing it has absolutely no effect. I mean, of course, the house-shaped-silhouette button, not the button with the word "home". The latter one works just perfect on M10.